# how to search the value of data from db whatever i enter in the text field on html

Tags: javascript, html

i used one text input with id....

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" id="textsearch">
```

i already created database..

this is my javascript code ....

```
$("#search").click(function(){
    var searchlist=$("#textsearch").val();
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS WHERE id LIKE '%searchlist%'');
  });
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
      var searchresult = results;
      msg = "<p>"+searchresult+"</p>";
      document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = msg;
    },null);
});
```

here status is div in html page
please help me i want to get the data from the db....

Comment: Should be `tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS WHERE id LIKE "%?%"', [searchlist]);` or `tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS WHERE id LIKE "%' + searchlist + '%"');`.

Comment: its working ....thnks....

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to search any value which is entered in the text field ,
This is a better idea to achieve this

1. Call a JavaScript function on a button click event (add a button in html for this like this)

2 declare a function called searchValue() {} in javascript.

3 here get the value of that text field .

4 After that here you need to create a php web service to search the string in database.

5 you can call that web service by $post method of jquery.